# Does C allocate memory for variables not define on the start of function?

Tags: c, memory, callstack

Here's my scenario why I ask this question:

```
static ProfileUnit* g_units_header;
static ProfileUnit* g_units_tail;
static int g_units_count;

void Destroy() {
    if (!g_units_header) {
        return;
    }

    typedef std::vector<ProfileUnit*> PUVect;
    PUVect stack(g_units_count);
    ProfileUnit* p = g_units_header;
    while (p) {
        stack.push_back(p);
        p = p->next;
    }
    for (PUVect::const_iterator it = stack.begin(); it != stack.end(); ++it) {
        free(*it);
    }

    g_units_header = g_units_tail = nullptr;
    g_units_count = 0;
}
```

Does the "stack" and "p" will on the call stack if "g_units_header" is nullptr? It's not a very good example, I just want to explain the scenario. just focus on the question.

Comment: That example is too simple. Any good compiler will optimize it away to nothing, regardless of p.

Comment: depend on compiler

Comment: If `p` is null, then the program doesn't access `val`, so it doesn't matter where the compiler puts it. It could put on the moon, as far as your program is concerned. (This is known as the "as-if" rule.)

Comment: @usrbin: The updated example makes answers, such as mine below, appear disconnected from the question, while not really changing the fact that `val` can be optimized away completely (the newly added code is equivalent to `return 1`).

Comment: @NPE I update the code, just use my real code.

Comment: Not only did you completely change the code in you question, you changed it to C++ although the question is tagged C. Please don't do that. SO is not a dialog; it is a repository of questions and answers intended to have long-term use. Questions can be modified to make them more precise, but not to be different questions. If you change the question, existing answers are disconnected, which is unfair to the responder and unuseful to later readers.

Comment: If you are wondering whether `stack`'s destructor will be called if the gloval isNULL, that's not a bad question but you really need to ask it as a new post, making sure to use the C++ tag. (The destructor won't run,  but the full explanation won't fit in a comment.)

Comment: @rici I am sorry for that. I don't know how to modify the question than change it, but I never do that again, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(For illustration I'll use a slight variation of the code in the original version of your question. You have since edited the question to change the code, but that doesn't change the answer.)*

In practice, the answer depends on the compiler and optimisation options used. Some possible outcomes:

1. `val` is optimised away completely irrespective of the value of `p`.
2. `val` is placed in a register (does that count as "memory"?)
3. `val` is placed on the stack irrespective of the value of `p`.
4. `val` is placed on the stack only if `p` is not `NULL`.

On my machine, `gcc -O3` does #4:

```
$ cat test.c
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(int* p) {
    if (!p) return;
    int val = 0xdeadbeef;
    scanf("%d", &val);
}
```

Compiled:

```
$ gcc -S -O3 test.c
```

Output (edited for brevity):

```
$ cat test.s
_foo:                                   ## @foo
    testq   %rdi, %rdi  ## <<< p == NULL?
    je  LBB0_2          ## <<< Will jump over the stack allocation below
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    subq    $16, %rsp   ## <<< Allocate stack for val
    movl    $-559038737, -4(%rbp)   ## 0xdeadbeef
    leaq    L_.str(%rip), %rdi
    leaq    -4(%rbp), %rsi
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    callq   _scanf
    addq    $16, %rsp   ## <<< Deallocate val
    popq    %rbp
LBB0_2:
    retq
```

Answer (score 0):

Although a compiler has a lot of leeway, particularly with code which can be proven to not produce any observable effects, the C standard does specify that the lifetime of an automatic variable (a local variable) begins at entry to the block in which it is declared (which is the body of `foo` on the case you are asking about.) [Note 1]

Until the declaration is reached during execution of `foo` -- if it is reached -- the variable has an indeterminate value, which limits its use. Also, the variable's name is not visible prior to its declaration. However, the variable does exist (unless it has been eliminated because the compiler has determined that it is irrelevant).

On the whole, this is not worth worrying about. "Allocating" an automatic variable normally consists of decrementing the stack pointer on function entry; this is done just once by summing the size of all the function's automatic variables. Computers are not limited to counting on their fingers; they can subtract a big number from the stack pointer in the same amount of time as it would take to subtract a small number. The only time you might notice this effect is if your function has megabytes of local variables. You should avoid doing that.

---

#### Notes:

1. Variable-length arrays are an exception to this rule, since they cannot be allocated until their size is known, which cannot be determined until the declaration is actually evaluated.